# How to determine the actual level of development in a shop, e.g. C++ vs. C?

Tags: c++

I imagine most of you know what I am getting at.  You start a new job and within the first week or so of scanning through the code you realize you are in yet another C shop that throws in the occasional stream or hapless user defined class here and there.  You quickly realize that not only aren't you going to learn anything new but it is just a matter of time before you are asked not use certain things because no one else understands them and won't be able to maintain your work.

How often do you see some new technique on say, StackOverflow, only to realize that if you ever used it at work you would be met with bewilderment or annoyance at best?

In your experience are these places the norm or the exception?

How do (or would) you try to determine a group's level of sophistication and commitment to C++ in the interview setting?  For instance I have tried asking questions about the company's use of things like STL, Boost, 3rd party libs, etc., but that only seems to get incrementally closer to the reality of situation you'll find once in it.  Thoughts?

Comment: There's a real question in there somewhere, but i'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: It's about employment experience, and really should be community wiki.  Simply, how often do you encounter shops that are a whole lot more backward than they advertise, and how do you avoid them?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got closed. +1 to reopen

Comment: I'm all about the reopen, as originally worded. I'm curious how C++ is used throughout the industry.

Comment: I think you should keep C++ in the title, since this question only really makes sense in a C++ context. C# or C code is pretty much the same regardless of where you are. C++ can mean completely different things, ranging from "C with classes" and all the way up to Boost/template metaprogramming

Comment: "but it is just a matter of time before you are asked not use certain things because no one else understands them" This is the crux of the question many of the answerers are missing. Perhaps this should be bold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really all across the board. On one end of the spectrum, I've worked in one place where the code was recently rewritten in C. Recently being 10 years ago. Everyone was highly skeptical of this new-fangled technology.

Slightly farther down the spectrum, you'll find C programmers who happen to have compilers with C++ features enabled. They'll dabble in the "class" keyword. But other than that, they are practically writing in C.

Next down the line I think you'll find those who just groked inheritance and polymorphism. These are the kind of guys and gals that would swoon over an MFC or wxWidgets program, thinking it was the greatest.

You'll go a little farther and find the folks who just read Meyer. They are all about figuring out how to use STL efficiently. They've got a basic notion of templates that equates mostly to the way STL uses them.

Then you've got the Modern C++ Template Metaprogramming geeks. Many of us these days use their work in the form of boost and all its goodness. Few actually dork around with template metaprogramming. That's probably a good thing.

I have seen perfectly good code written at each level.

The cool thing I always liked about C++ is that at each level of added complexity, the cost could be conceptualized in terms of "how this new abstraction might be implemented in C". So I can conceptualize that inheritance and polymorphism is adding the cost of a function pointer lookup. Since I have seen this and written this in C, I know what I'm in for. I also have a sense of how templates work in part because of how the preprocessor works in C. This applies to most features in the C++ and C world.

Since it's easy to map concepts to how they are implemented in C, I can easily visualize how the underlying architecture runs my code.

Comment: This is a good rundown but doesn't answer the stated question: How do (or would) you try to determine a group's level of sophistication and commitment to C++ in the interview setting?

Comment: Maybe you are right, it seems the question has changed somewhat from the original title of "How many "real" C++ shops have you worked in?" with questions focused on our experience in the field. Its true I don't answer the second part about how to determine the level of development.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  This catches the spirit of what I was asking and pretty well matches my experience with the industry as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you read between the lines, you'll probably find a heck of a lot of information buried in their questions, both in terms of what they want you for and their level of sophistication.

You may also want to return their questions not only with answers, but with harder questions requiring clarification on ambiguities in their questions.

Just don't come off as an arrogant jerk when you do it.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The places I've worked at weren't necessarily using C soley.  They weren't cranking out new programs one after another...they were usually building something big and maintaining it.  In my experience it becomes harder to keep implementing new an exciting features of a language into an older piece of software that keeps growing and the main job is to maintain/update it.

I think asking in the interview about those cool new features would help a lot...you should at least be able to weed out the obvious ones.  Another thing would be to ask if you could talk to some of the people that actually write the code.  Most interviews are with manager types...and they aren't always the people involved with using the latest features of a language.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked for long periods of time in three C++ shops.  In all cases, they were real C++ shops, using C++ as it was intended to be used, and staying fairly up-to-date, given the times I worked at them.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them for a copy of their C++ coding standards document. That should give you some idea of the level they're working at. If they don't have one, that could be a bad sign.

Answer (score -2):

Interestingly, I consider the level of advancement pretty much the opposite of your preferences. Therefore this response might not be directly useful, but I hope it's at least somewhat informative.

---

First, any environment that encourages "cleverness" is suspect. If I see a lot of Boost, a lot of template metaprogramming, and especially any use of C++'s "functional" features, it's a big red warning sign. It means the developers have some idea of what correct programming is, but are constrained by either lack of imagination or politics to using a decrepit junk language such as C++. C is boring and tedious to work with, but "advanced" C++ goes out of its way to interfere with development.

Second, check whether a particular technology or concept is treated as a buzzword. If the prospective employer uses XML, there's an easy check you can do -- do they use a real parser/serializer (either SAX or DOM is fine), or do they parse it with regexes and serialize it with raw character streams? If the latter, it shows they don't understand *why* XML is useful, and they're just using it to have another three-letter acronym on the project description.

Third, figure out what language the developers *wish* they were using and why. Every good developer has a favorite obscure language -- it doesn't matter whether it's Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, Haskell, or Factor -- and a reason for preferring it. If everybody is content to work in C++, it's another warning sign that they've not got much curiosity about programming in general.

Comment: So using one language is a sign of lack of curiosity, but using that language to its full extent is also bad? ;)
Of course C++ can turn into a overcomplicated mess if you're not careful, but it can also remove a hell of a lot of complexity through application of the things you mention.

Comment: Attempts by programmers to work around a limiting language, instead of simply wrapping and slowly replacing it, is a sign that fresh ideas are not appreciated. I've never seen anything come out of template metaprogramming or macro hacks that couldn't be done better in a higher-level language.

Comment: @John.  The rule as always is right tool for the job. For a long term project - moving to the latest "buzz" technology it is wrong too. You even say that in your answer!  A shop working primarily in C++ is not by definition "bad".

Comment: No, using a modern or less popular technology is *not* bad. If I give the impression that I mean that, then my wording is wrong. I intend exactly the opposite -- a shop that does not keep up with recent developments is an awful place to work.